# Redundant LiPo protection circuit needed for charging application?

Tags: pcb, charging, lipo, tp4056

I want to charge a Lipo battery with a TP4056 circuit. Custom PCB.

The [Lipo](https://www.amazon.de/5000mAh-Stecker-6060100-Powerbank-Tablet/dp/B097HM3L8V) I want to use has an integrated protection circuit, but what is protected is not specified exactly.

In a typical TP4056 appliaction a Lipo protection is added with DW01A and FS8205A. [image]

Do I still need the DW01A and FS8205A for protection, or is this redundancy useless?